# Reactjs and Socket.io with nodejs not sending data to other clients

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Building chat application with Reactjs nodejs and socket.io.

When I run this code, it connects to server. when i send message for example from chrome browser, I can see the message I sent but
the other client in another browser is not getting any message.

All the messages sent are seen in the console log.

If I use 
`socket.broadcast.emit()` function, I cannot see the message that I sent but the other clients will see it and vice versa.

**How do I solve this issue so that both client can send see and recieve messages to and from each other.**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import axios from 'axios';
import io from "socket.io-client";


class ChatReact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 this.state = {

 username: '',
 message: '',
 messages: []

};

 this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount(){
this.socket = io('http://localhost:9090');

this.socket.on('connect',(data) => {
    this.socket.emit('joined', 'Hello World from client...');
 });

this.socket.on('acknowledge', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });




        this.socket.on('response message', function(data){
            addMessage(data);
        });

        const addMessage = data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data]});
            console.log(this.state.messages);
        };


}


 sendMessage = ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            this.socket.emit('chat message', {
                author: this.state.username,
                message: this.state.message
            })
            this.setState({message: ''});

        }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div>

 <div className="messages">
                                    {this.state.messages.map(message => {
                                        return (
                                            <div>{message.author}: {message.message}</div>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </div>





<h1> Testing Socket Io with Reactjs</h1>

 <div className="card-footer">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value={this.state.username} onChange={ev => this.setState({username: ev.target.value})} className="form-control"/>
                                <br/>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Message" className="form-control" value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
                                <br/>
                                <button onClick={this.sendMessage} className="btn btn-primary form-control">Send</button>
                            </div>




        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**here is the server response**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected now..');
    socket.on('joined', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('acknowledge', 'Acknowledged');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(data){
socket.emit('response message', data);
        //socket.broadcast.emit('response message', data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));


    });
});

http.listen(9090, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:9090');
});
```

Comment: I think you need to make a few changes. First, replace var http = require('http').Server(app) by var server = require('http').createServer(app). Second repalce var io = require('socket.io')(http) by var io = require('socket.io')(server). I hope it will work

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [socket.io cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) to understand who has to see the messages. "**broadcast**" clearly states to send messages to all clients **except the sender**. If you need to send a message for many users including the sender then better use the room method. Also take care of what instance are you using whether **socket** or **io** (instance of connection).

```
io.in('roomName').emit('acknowledge', 'Acknowledged')
```